# Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, console

How do I invoke a console application from my .NET application and capture all the output generated in the console?

(Remember, I don't want to save the information first in a file and then relist as I would love to receive it as live.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process.start: how to get the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Comment: Please see the dates on both questions and see which one is "duplicate"

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643)
If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on [Add clarification link to "Possible duplicate" automated comment](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/281980)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

This can be quite easily achieved using the [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) property. A full sample is contained in the linked MSDN documentation; the only caveat is that you may have to redirect the standard error stream as well to see all output of your application.

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If you don't want the extra new line at the end, just use `Console.Write` instead.

Comment: It should be noted that if you use ReadToEnd() in combination with a console application that has the capability to prompt the user for input.
Eg: Overwrite File: Y or N?  etc
Then ReadToEnd can result in a memory leak, since the process never exits while waiting for user input.
The safer way to capture output is to use the 
process.OutputDataReceived event handler and let the process notify your application of output to be received.

Comment: How to capture if in case the code is deployed to azure webapp, since the compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe"; might not exists!

Answer (score 61):

This is bit improvement over accepted answer from **@mdb**. Specifically, we also capture error output of the process. Additionally, we capture these outputs through events because `ReadToEnd()` doesn't work if you want to capture *both* error and regular output. It took me while to make this work because it actually also requires `BeginxxxReadLine()` calls after `Start()`.

Asynchronous way:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process process = new Process();

void LaunchProcess()
{
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
    process.Exited += new System.EventHandler(process_Exited);

    process.StartInfo.FileName = "some.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1 param2";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();          

    //below line is optional if we want a blocking call
    //process.WaitForExit();
}

void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("process exited with code {0}\n", process.ExitCode.ToString()));
}

void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\n");
}

void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\n");
}
```

Comment: this is easily understandable, beautiful code.  My only nitpick is you are unnecessarily adding newlines.  The "writeline" adds one for you, so the net effect is your captured output has an empty line inserted every other line.

Comment: Is there a synchronous way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Use [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to redirect the output when creating your console process.

Then you can use [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) to read the program output.

The second link has a sample code how to do it.

Answer (score 12):

[ConsoleAppLauncher](https://github.com/slavagu/ConsoleAppLauncher) is an open source library made specifically to answer that question. It captures all the output generated in the console and provides simple interface to start and close console application.

The ConsoleOutput event is fired every time when a new line is written by the console to standard/error output. The lines are queued and guaranteed to follow the output order.

Also available as [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/ConsoleAppLauncher/).

Sample call to get full console output:

```
// Run simplest shell command and return its output.
public static string GetWindowsVersion()
{
    return ConsoleApp.Run("cmd", "/c ver").Output.Trim();
}
```

Sample with live feedback:

```
// Run ping.exe asynchronously and return roundtrip times back to the caller in a callback
public static void PingUrl(string url, Action<string> replyHandler)
{
    var regex = new Regex("(time=|Average = )(?<time>.*?ms)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var app = new ConsoleApp("ping", url);
    app.ConsoleOutput += (o, args) =>
    {
        var match = regex.Match(args.Line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var roundtripTime = match.Groups["time"].Value;
            replyHandler(roundtripTime);
        }
    };
    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added a number of helper methods to the [O2 Platform](http://o2platform.com) (Open Source project) which allow you easily script an interaction with another process via the console output and input (see http://code.google.com/p/o2platform/source/browse/trunk/O2_Scripts/APIs/Windows/CmdExe/CmdExeAPI.cs)

Also useful for you might be the API that allows the viewing of the console output of the current process (in an existing control or popup window). See this blog post for more details: http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/api_consoleout-cs-inprocess-capture-of-the-console-output/ (this blog also contains details of how to consume the console output of new processes)

Comment: Since then I've added more support for using the ConsoleOut (in this case if you start the .NET process your self). Take a look at:
[How to use the Console output in the C# REPL](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/how-to-use-the-console-output-in-the-c-repl-2/) , [Adding 'Console Out' to VisualStudio IDE as a native Window](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2012/11/adding-console-out-to-visualstudio-ide.html) , [Viewing 'Console Out' messages created inside UserControls](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2012/11/viewing-console-out-messages-created.html)

Answer (score 2):

I made a reactive version that accepts callbacks for stdOut and StdErr.
`onStdOut` and `onStdErr` are called asynchronously,
as soon as data arrives (before the process exits).

```
public static Int32 RunProcess(String path,
                               String args,
                       Action<String> onStdOut = null,
                       Action<String> onStdErr = null)
    {
        var readStdOut = onStdOut != null;
        var readStdErr = onStdErr != null;

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = path,
                Arguments = args,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = readStdOut,
                RedirectStandardError = readStdErr,
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        if (readStdOut) Task.Run(() => ReadStream(process.StandardOutput, onStdOut));
        if (readStdErr) Task.Run(() => ReadStream(process.StandardError, onStdErr));

        process.WaitForExit();

        return process.ExitCode;
    }

    private static void ReadStream(TextReader textReader, Action<String> callback)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var line = textReader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;

            callback(line);
        }
    }
```

### Example usage

The following will run `executable` with `args` and print

- stdOut in white
- stdErr in red

to the console.

```
RunProcess(
    executable,
    args,
    s => { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; Console.WriteLine(s); },
    s => { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;   Console.WriteLine(s); } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

From *[PythonTR - Python Programcıları Derneği, e-kitap, örnek](http://pythontr.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50:python-script-lerinin-c-ile-caltrlmas-execute-python-script-in-c&catid=31:makale&Itemid=66)*:

```
Process p = new Process();   // Create new object
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  // Do not use shell
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   // Redirect output
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\python26\\python.exe";   // Path of our Python compiler
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\python26\\Hello_C_Python.py";   // Path of the .py to be executed
```

Answer (score 1):

Added `process.StartInfo.**CreateNoWindow** = true;` and `timeout`.

```
private static void CaptureConsoleAppOutput(string exeName, string arguments, int timeoutMilliseconds, out int exitCode, out string output)
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();

        output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        bool exited = process.WaitForExit(timeoutMilliseconds);
        if (exited)
        {
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        }
        else
        {
            exitCode = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` it won't return to next statement until end of app. so your timeout in WaitForExit(timeoutMilliseconds) does not work! (your code will hang!)