# How to write a vb.net code to compile C/C++ programs?

Tags: c#, c++, python, c, vb.net

I'm trying to make a vb.net application that has got 2 textboxes, 7 radio buttons and 2 buttons(one named compile and the other 'run'). How can I load the content of a C/C++(or any programming language) file into the 1st textbox and on clicking the compile button, i should be able to show the errors or the C/C++ program in the 2nd textbox. On clicking Run, I should be able to show the output in the 2nd textbox. In short, I want to use the 2nd textbox as a terminal/console. The radio buttons are 4 selecting the language C or C++ or python or C# or java or perl or vb.
Are the compilers of all these languages present in .net? If so how can I call them?

Comment: Did you ask this recently, possibly under a different name?  We really don't like dupes.

Comment: We also do not like things like "R d", "dem" or "?????". Well, at least I do.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `System.IO` namespace for clues as to how you go about loading the contents of a file into a text box. In particular, the `File` class.

[System.IO.File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

Look at the `System.Diagnostics` namespace for clues as to how to go about launching a process and capturing the output. In particular, the `Process` class.

[System.Diagnostics.Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

This SO page...

[Capturing the Console Output in .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c)

... will give you some more info around capturing console output.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling can be done by calling cl.exe which comes with Visual Studio. Of course you could also use GCC instead.