# Command Param for making console invisible

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console, cmd

I am firing up a cmd console from my .net app with some parameters, is there a parameter to specify that the cmd console is not visible?

---- Edit - Adding Code

I know this isn't the standard way of starting a process in .Net, but it is being run from a Silverlight Client.

```
  Dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    cmd.Run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c *myargs*")
```

Comment: This question may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/c-hiding-a-console-window

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? There are several ways to "fire up" a console application, and it would help to see the code.

Comment: Pretty sure my solution won't work for you... deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging, I have found out that this will work -

```
   Dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    cmd.Run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c *myargs*",0,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never want the application to show a console window, one way is, after creating the console application, to change the application Output Type to "Windows Application" (project properties / Application tab / Output type).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this solution:

[Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-console-application)

or alternatively, make your project a GUI project but without any forms and use the classes in the System.Diagnostics namespace to execute your commands. Probably requires much refactoring though.