# Hide the console (completely) for a Console app, but only sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a C# Console app than runs a pre-build step (to get NuGet Packages).

When I am debugging this, I want to pass in a parameter and show the console.  When I am not debugging it I don't want to see it.  I don't even want it to flash up there for a second.

I have found ways to hide it, after it has shown.  But I can't find a way to never make it show unless I am willing to change it from a console app to a Windows app.  (Which I would do if I could then find a way to show the Console when needed.)

Comment: I think this is a good solution for your problem.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/c-hiding-a-console-window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/c-hiding-a-console-window

Comment: I think this is the solution for your problem :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/c-hiding-a-console-window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563744/c-hiding-a-console-window

Comment: @Talke: Not quite a duplicate – the other Q doesn't include the "only sometimes" part.

Answer (score 2):

Build as a Windows application and show the console when you need it. To show the console when needed use P/Invoke to call [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.AllocConsole) has the declaration you need).

(Console sub-system processes *always* get a console, their parent process's if there was one, otherwise a new one. This is the way Windows works at a deep level.)

Comment: aren't all applications windows applications? ;)

Comment: He's talking about the name of the setting in Project + Properties, Application tab.

Answer (score -1):

Use `FreeConsole` WINAPI function:

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FreeConsole.html

Another solution is to simply switch to a WinForms application as project type. No console will be allocated then (and you do not need to show a form).

Comment: FreeConsole has the same problems as ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE).  It only helps for an already existing console.  I want it to never appear in the first place.

Comment: Read the "Another solution" part. The fact is that you can never hide a console from start when you have specified "console application" as project type.