# Capture coloured console output from multiple sources

Tags: delphi, process, output, console-application

I wrote a console application that is able to execute multiple commands on the command line in parallel.
Primarily I did this out of interest and because the build processes of the software projects I am working on make excessive use of the command line.

Currently, before I create a child process in a worker thread, I create an anonymous pipe in order to capture all the output the child process creates during its lifetime.
After the child process terminates, the worker thread pushes the captured content to the waiting main process that then prints it out.

Here's my process creations and capturing:

```
    procedure ReadPipe(const ReadHandle: THandle; const Output: TStream);
    var
      Buffer: TMemoryStream;
      BytesRead, BytesToRead: DWord;
    begin
      Buffer := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        BytesRead := 0;
        BytesToRead := 0;

        if PeekNamedPipe(ReadHandle, nil, 0, nil, @BytesToRead, nil) then
        begin
          if BytesToRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer.Size := BytesToRead;
            ReadFile(ReadHandle, Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size, BytesRead, nil);

            if Buffer.Size <> BytesRead then
            begin
              Buffer.Size := BytesRead;
            end;

            if Buffer.Size > 0 then
            begin
              Output.Size := Output.Size + Buffer.Size;
              Output.WriteBuffer(Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Buffer.Free;
      end;
    end;

    function CreateProcessWithRedirectedOutput(const AppName, CMD, DefaultDir: PChar; out CapturedOutput: String): Cardinal;
    const
      TIMEOUT_UNTIL_NEXT_PIPEREAD = 100;
    var
      SecurityAttributes: TSecurityAttributes;
      ReadHandle, WriteHandle: THandle;
      StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
      ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
      ProcessStatus: Cardinal;
      Output: TStringStream;
    begin
      Result := 0;
      CapturedOutput := '';
      Output := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        SecurityAttributes.nLength := SizeOf(SecurityAttributes);
        SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
        SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;

        if CreatePipe(ReadHandle, WriteHandle, @SecurityAttributes, 0) then
        begin
          try
            FillChar(StartupInfo, Sizeof(StartupInfo), 0);
            StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
            StartupInfo.hStdOutput := WriteHandle;
            StartupInfo.hStdError := WriteHandle;
            StartupInfo.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
            StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

            if CreateProcess(AppName, CMD,
                             @SecurityAttributes, @SecurityAttributes,
                             True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                             nil, DefaultDir,
                             StartupInfo, ProcessInformation)
            then
            begin

              try
                repeat
                  ProcessStatus := WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, TIMEOUT_UNTIL_NEXT_PIPEREAD);
                  ReadPipe(ReadHandle, Output);
                until ProcessStatus <> WAIT_TIMEOUT;

                if not Windows.GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, Result) then
                begin
                  Result := GetLastError;
                end;

              finally
                Windows.CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
                Windows.CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
              end;
            end
            else
            begin
              Result := GetLastError;
            end;

          finally
            Windows.CloseHandle(ReadHandle);
            Windows.CloseHandle(WriteHandle);
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          Result := GetLastError;
        end;

        CapturedOutput := Output.DataString;
      finally
        Output.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

My problem now:
**This method doesn't preserve potential coloring of the captured output!**

I came accross this topic [Capture coloured console output into WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529254/capture-coloured-console-output-into-wpf-application) but that didn't help me out, as I don't receive any color data through the anonymous pipe, just plain old text.

I experimented with inheriting the console of the main process to the child processes via [CreateFile with 'CONOUT$'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#consoles), but while the colors are indeed preserved, you probably can guess that its pure mayhem if more than one process prints out its contents into one and the same console.

My next approach was to create additional console buffers with [CreateConsoleScreenBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) for each child process and read the contents with [ReadConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole), but that wasn't successful as ReadConsole returns with System Error 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

```
    ConsoleHandle := CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
       GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
       FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
       @SecurityAttributes,
       CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
       nil);
    //...    
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput := ConsoleHandle;
    StartupInfo.hStdError := ConsoleHandle;
    //...
    ConsoleOutput := TMemoryStream.Create
    ConsoleOutput.Size := MAXWORD;
    ConsoleOutput.Position := 0;
    ReadConsole(ConsoleHandle, ConsoleOutput.Memory, ConsoleOutput.Size, CharsRead, nil) // Doesn't read anything and returns with System Error Code 6.
```

I also read up on [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) and [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole), [AttachConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) and [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole), but can't quite wrap my head around it for my use case.

**What is the right/best way to preserve/receive coloring information of the console output of a child process?**

Comment: @J... Thanks for the input. I edited the Question and removed unnecessary information. I hope it's better now. I will also take a deeper look into SetConsoleMode and its surroundings.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but i wanted to point out a common problem that keeps coming up in code where people read the output from a child process. They use things like WaitForSingleObject to try to figure out when the spawned child process has exited. [That's the wrong way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560929/12597) This doesn't help you with your problem; i'm just trying to rid the world of `ReadPipe`/`MsgWait` one bug at a time.

Comment: Your link "Capture coloured console output into WPF application" describes the problem and solution - you have to interpret the control/escape codes and keep track of the current attribute settings separately for each stream as attributes apply until changed.

Comment: @Brian My problem is: There are no control/escape codes in the bits and bytes of the output. As I wrote in the Question, I only get plain old text.

Comment: @IanBoyd I need to think about that. I don't like the blocking nature of ReadFile. That's why I loop periodically and peek the pipe for content prior reading. It introduces a bit of overhead for the thread and potentially delay for the child process, but leaves me with full control over my Thread. If I understand correctly, my design decision will still lead to the child process being able to finish. At some point the child process will have written every thing, I will have read everything and WaitForSingleObject will come back with something other than WAIT_TIMEOUT. Or do I miss something?

Comment: [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), include `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT `.  Note the guidance `The typical usage of this flag is intended in conjunction with ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING on the output handle to connect to an application that communicates exclusively via virtual terminal sequences.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right track with [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) and giving each thread its own console screen buffer.
The problem was [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) which doesn't do what I expected.
**I now got it working with [`ReadConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutput).**

It should be noted however, that this method is the legacy way of doing it.
If you want to do it the "new way" you should probably use [Pseudo Console Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session).
Its support starts with Windows 10 1809 and Windows Server 2019.

It should also be noted, that the method of reading the output of a process/program via console screen buffer has its flaws and two distinct disadvantages compared to anonymous pipes:

1. The console screen buffer can't get full and block the process/program, but if the end of it is reached, new lines will push the current first line out of the buffer.
2. Output from processes/programs that spam their std output in a fast fashion will most likely lead to loss of information, as you won't be able to read, clear and move the cursor in the console screen buffer fast enough.

I try to circumvent both by increasing the console screen buffers y size component to its maximum possible size (I found it to be `MAXSHORT - 1`) and just wait until the process/program has finished.
That's good enough for me, as I don't need to analyze or process the colored output, but just display it in a console window, which is itself limited to `MAXSHORT - 1` lines.
**In every other scenario I will be using pipes and advise everyone else to do so too!**

Here is a short version without any error handling that can be executed in parallel without interference (provided the TStream object is owned by the thread or thread-safe):

```
procedure CreateProcessWithConsoleCapture(const aAppName, aCMD, aDefaultDir: PChar;
  const CapturedOutput: TStream);
const
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE_Y = MAXSHORT - 1;
var
  SecurityAttributes: TSecurityAttributes;
  ConsoleHandle: THandle;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  CharsRead: Cardinal;
  BufferSize, Origin: TCoord;
  ConsoleScreenBufferInfo: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
  Buffer: array of TCharInfo;
  ReadRec: TSmallRect;
begin
  SecurityAttributes.nLength := SizeOf(SecurityAttributes);
  SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := Nil;
  SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;

  ConsoleHandle := CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
     GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
     FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
     @SecurityAttributes,
     CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
     nil);
  
  try
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ConsoleHandle, ConsoleScreenBufferInfo);
    BufferSize.X := ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwSize.X;
    BufferSize.Y := CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE_Y;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(ConsoleHandle, BufferSize);

    Origin.X := 0;
    Origin.Y := 0;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(ConsoleHandle, #0, BufferSize.X * BufferSize.Y, Origin, CharsRead);

    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, ConsoleHandle);

    FillChar(StartupInfo, Sizeof(StartupInfo), 0);
    StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput := ConsoleHandle;
    StartupInfo.hStdError := ConsoleHandle;
    StartupInfo.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK;

    CreateProcess(aAppName, aCMD,
      @SecurityAttributes, @SecurityAttributes,
      True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
      nil, aDefaultDir,
      StartupInfo, ProcessInformation);

    try
      WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);

      GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ConsoleHandle, ConsoleScreenBufferInfo);

      BufferSize.X := ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwSize.X;
      BufferSize.Y := ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y;

      if ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.X > 0 then
      begin
        Inc(BufferSize.Y);
      end;

      ReadRec.Left := 0;
      ReadRec.Top := 0;
      ReadRec.Right := BufferSize.X - 1;
      ReadRec.Bottom := BufferSize.Y - 1;

      SetLength(Buffer, BufferSize.X * BufferSize.Y);
      ReadConsoleOutput(ConsoleHandle, @Buffer[0], BufferSize, Origin, ReadRec);

      CharsRead := SizeOf(TCharInfo) * (ReadRec.Right - ReadRec.Left + 1) * (ReadRec.Bottom - ReadRec.Top + 1);
      if CharsRead > 0 then
      begin
        CapturedOutput.Size := CapturedOutput.Size + CharsRead;
        CapturedOutput.WriteBuffer(Buffer[0], CharsRead);
      end;

    finally
      CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(ConsoleHandle);
  end;
end;
```