# Redirecting standard output when generated

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to redirect the output of a c program which generates output in the console. I can redirect the output once the process exits. But is there the way to redirect the output as and when there is some output in the shell window? I require this to make it understandable that the program is running and since different steps of the c code may take, say 10-15 minutes to run.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing the Console Output in .NET (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c)

Comment: The "Possible Duplicate" question is an exact duplicate. The question is asked for C#, but the links are to MSDN documentation for both C# and Vb.Net

Comment: I dont agree that this is a exact duplicate. There is in one hand capturing console out, which works fine for me & i didn't asked for that. What I need is that is there any method which can help me get the output from console as and when they are written in the console or should I have to wait for the process to exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the code that you're using is using [`ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) on the StreamReader. If so, just use [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx) or [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) to get access to the stream as its written.