# How to get the video duration using FFMPEG in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg, process

I want to get the video file duration in string using C#. I searched the internet and all i get is:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi
```

And every1 say that parse the output for duration.

Here is my code which is

```
string filargs = "-y -i " + inputavi + " -ar 22050 " + outputflv;
    Process proc;
    proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = filargs;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    try
    {
        proc.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        proc.WaitForExit(50 * 1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    finally
    {
        proc.Close();
    }
```

Now please tell me how can i save the output string and parse it for the video duration.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c

Answer (score 7):

There is another Option to get Video Length ,by using Media Info [DLL](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

Using Ffmpeg :

```
proc.StartInfo.RedirectErrorOutput = true;
string message = proc.ErrorOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Filtering shouldn't be an issue ,so do it you're self.

PS : using ffmpeg you should not read the StandardOutput but ErrorOutput i dont know why ,but it work's only like that.

Comment: Thanks man your code didnt work instead i used following code:

'proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string message = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();'

But thanks anyway, you showed me the first step, which eventually turn out well for for me.
Stay Blesses!!!

Answer (score 5):

FFmpeg is a little bit of an adventure to parse. But in any case, here's what you need to know.

**First, FFmpeg doesn't play well with RedirectOutput options**

What you'll need to do is instead of launching ffmpeg directly, launch `cmd.exe`, passing in ffmpeg as an argument, and redirecting the output to a "monitor file" through a command line output like so... note that in the `while (!proc.HasExited)` loop you can read this file for real-time FFmpeg status, or just read it at the end if this is a quick operation.

```
        FileInfo monitorFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(ffMpegExe.Directory.FullName, "FFMpegMonitor_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt"));

        string ffmpegpath = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\cmd.exe"; 
        string ffmpegargs = "/C " + ffMpegExe.FullName + " " + encodeArgs + " 2>" + monitorFile.FullName;

        string fullTestCmd = ffmpegpath + " " + ffmpegargs;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ffmpegpath, ffmpegargs);
        psi.WorkingDirectory = ffMpegExe.Directory.FullName;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.Verb = "runas";

        var proc = Process.Start(psi);

        while (!proc.HasExited)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        string encodeLog = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(monitorFile.FullName);
```

Great, now you've got the log of what FFmpeg just spit out. Now to get the duration. **The duration line will look something like this:**

`Duration: 00:10:53.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9963 kb/s`

Clean up the results into a `List<string>`:

```
var encodingLines = encodeLog.Split(System.Environment.NewLine[0]).Where(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()) == false).Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
```

**... then loop through them looking for** `Duration`.

```
        foreach (var line in encodingLines)
        {
            // Duration: 00:10:53.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9963 kb/s
            if (line.StartsWith("Duration"))
            {
                var duration = ParseDurationLine(line);
            }
        }
```

**Here's some code that can do the parse for you:**

```
    private TimeSpan ParseDurationLine(string line)
    {
        var itemsOfData = line.Split(" "[0], "="[0]).Where(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) == false).Select(s => s.Trim().Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty)).ToList();

        string duration = GetValueFromItemData(itemsOfData, "Duration:");

        return TimeSpan.Parse(duration);
    }

    private string GetValueFromItemData(List<string> items, string targetKey)
    {
        var key = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ToUpper() == targetKey.ToUpper());

        if (key == null) { return null; }
        var idx = items.IndexOf(key);

        var valueIdx = idx + 1;

        if (valueIdx >= items.Count)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return items[valueIdx];
    }
```

Comment: Sorry dude! I am unable to understand your code. Where will my inputavi file will fit in of which i want to find the duration??? Also explain the variables u hav used e.g., "encodeArgs" What is it.

Comment: your code is working fine which shows info about ffmpeg  when used ffmpeg as input. How can i use this to send my avi file as input and get its info??? Thanks Anyways. Yu are doing great

Comment: What if there is a metadata with name Duration and Value "00:00:00"? Security is not perfect

Answer (score 1):

Just check it out::

```
    //Create varriables

    string ffMPEG = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ffMPEG.exe");
    system.Diagnostics.Process mProcess = null;

    System.IO.StreamReader SROutput = null;
    string outPut = "";

    string filepath = "D:\\source.mp4";
    string param = string.Format("-i \"{0}\"", filepath);

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo oInfo = null;

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = null;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = null;
    TimeSpan Duration =  null;

    //Get ready with ProcessStartInfo
    oInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ffMPEG, param);
    oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    //ffMPEG uses StandardError for its output.
    oInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    oInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Lets start the process

    mProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo);

    // Divert output
    SROutput = mProcess.StandardError;

    // Read all
    outPut = SROutput.ReadToEnd();

    // Please donot forget to call WaitForExit() after calling SROutput.ReadToEnd

    mProcess.WaitForExit();
    mProcess.Close();
    mProcess.Dispose();
    SROutput.Close();
    SROutput.Dispose();

    //get duration

    re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[D|d]uration:.((\\d|:|\\.)*)");
    m = re.Match(outPut);

    if (m.Success) {
        //Means the output has cantained the string "Duration"
        string temp = m.Groups(1).Value;
        string[] timepieces = temp.Split(new char[] {':', '.'});
        if (timepieces.Length == 4) {

            // Store duration
            Duration = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[0]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[1]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[2]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[3]));
        }
    }
```

With thanks,
Gouranga Das.