# Command line program/app + C# class method

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, class-method

When working with a command line program, via a c# class method.

How do you determine if the commandline program was successfully executed and the operation it has performed is ok or has failed?

Also how do you get the screen commandline output into the c# class method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing the Console Output in .NET (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Process class to execute a command line command.

The following code captures the standard output to `output`, and assigns the processes exit code to `exitCode`.

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
}
```

Comment: I will also write the console app, how do you set the exitCode in the console app? just return the code after it completes execution right?

Comment: Just return the errorlevel code from Main(). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Process mycommand = new Process();
mycommand.StartInfo.FileName = "myexe.exe";
mycommand.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1";
mycommand.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
mycommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
mycommand.Start();    
Console.WriteLine(mycommand.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
mycommand.WaitForExit();
```

You usually determine an exe's state wether the exit code is 0, but that is arguably down to the writer of the exe

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `Process` class to call the command line app.

You can find the exit code of the process using [`Process.ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx). You can redirect its standard output by setting [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) before starting it, and then either using [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) or the [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c).

The additional information you might need is `process.ExitCode` to see if it was sucessful.  Of course, the Main method of the console app must return an exit code when it is unsuccessful, which many do not.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you use the `Process.Start` method. You can control how the process runs with the passed in `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
var myProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
  FileName = "process.exe",
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  CreateNoWindow = true
});
if (!myProcess.WaitForExit(5000)) { // give it 5 seconds to exit
  myProcess.Kill();
}
if (myProcess.ExitCode != 0) {
  // error!
}
var output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // access output
```