# Getting the ouput from Console window into Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have a console application which does a set of operations and gives out messages after completion of each operation. When I run my console app, the messages in my console window may look like this:

```
Checking prerequisites...
Completing prerequisites..
Performing installation...
Completing installation...
Done..!
```

Now I'm executing this console application from one of my C# windows applications by using Process.StartInfo().
I need to get all the messages thrown by my console application to be displayed in the windows form of my application.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing the Console Output in .NET (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c)

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite easily achieved using the ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property. A full sample is contained in the linked [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```