# Visual C # process arguments not working

Tags: c#

ok this was working the other day and now it's not... i don't remember changing anything, but i can run this reg.exe command with the arguments below from CMD and it works fine and creates the output file. but running it in VC# it does not create the file test_output.txt???

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc_cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\reg.exe";
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"query ""HKLM\Software\test\test software"" /v BuildNumber >c:\test\test_output.txt";
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc_cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc_cmd.Start();
    proc_cmd.Close();
```

Comment: *Vistual C # process*? What is this beast? Haven't met it yet.

Comment: @thanosazlin - since you got solution of your problem don't you feel an urge to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `Registry` class instead.

Comment: Just some extra info here.  After some testing I found that running reg.exe from against HKLM\SOFTWARE at commandline and from a .net process yields 2 different result sets.  So I think that using reg.exe from a process will not yield the expected output which really is irrelevant since it is much better to use Registry as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your `>output.txt` is an instruction to the command interpreter (cmd.exe).  That won't work calling `reg.exe`.  Consider calling `cmd.exe` instead, or redirecting the stdout and writing it to the file yourself.  See this [SO answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-the-console-output-in-net-c).

Of course, if there's no compelling reason to shell out to the Reg.exe, you should use the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class.