# Capturing an c# executable output from another C# program

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, outputstream

I am executing a C# program i.e a  .exe from another C# program.  but the .exe has some Console.WriteLine() in its program. I want to get the standard output into my C# program.

for example,

Consider a C# executable i.e 1.exe and there is another Program 2.cs.

I am calling from 2.cs 1.exe.  Now there is some output that the console is displaying from 1. exe. But I want the ouput in my program 2.cs. for displaying information to user.

Is it possible? Please help

Thanks
Sai sindhu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

Comment: please remember to search stack overflow for similar questions before posting.  Also pay attention to the suggested questions that pop up as you create your question - I'm almost certain the above question would have shown up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect the standard output stream, have a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) for more information.

> When a Process writes text to its standard stream, that text is
>   normally displayed on the console. By redirecting the StandardOutput
>   stream, you can manipulate or suppress the output of a process. For
>   example, you can filter the text, format it differently, or write the
>   output to both the console and a designated log file.