# Catch console input-output

Tags: c#

I have a console application that reads input from console and writes output to console. I need to write another program that should run the first one, mock the console input for it and grab the output. Can you please provide a way of investigation for this problem?

The (very easy) example of console application code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int value = int.Parse(input);
Console.WriteLine(value * value);
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? Show your console application code..

Comment: The fact is I really don't know how to begin.

Comment: Have you looked at all at the `Process` object? It has plenty of tools to make it easy to read/write from/to the console of a started application.

Comment: Start looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380330/capturing-an-c-sharp-executable-output-from-another-c-sharp-program)

Comment: This question should put you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the new `Process` and assign it's `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` properties.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = 
  new ProcessStartInfo(executableName, executableParameter);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
bool processStarted = process.Start();
StreamWriter inputWriter = process.StandardInput;
StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errorReader = process.StandardError;
//Write and read process console using inputWriter and outputReader.
process.WaitForExit();
```