# How do I redirect the process of executable in commandline?

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

I have an executable called outtext.exe which writes some output to console. I want to write this output directly to file in the commandline. I know I can capture the output from the Process object but now I just want to use my command as is.

I thought I could:

```
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    psi.FileName = "c:\sourcefiles\test\outtest.exe"
    psi.Arguments = "> c:\outfile.txt"
    psi.UseShellExecute = False
    Process.Start(psi)
```

The problem is that no "outfile.txt" is created. How can I make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I am sure your question read differently when I marked it as duplicate. The non-existing edit log however proves that I am wrong. Sorry for being too fast and reading your question sloppily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file redirection to C:\outfile.txt is a feature of the `cmd` process. You could try to do something like:

```
psi.FileName = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
psi.Arguments = "/c c:\sourcefiles\test\outtest.exe > C:\outfile.txt"
```