# Get CMD output in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, output

i'm using a syntax check programm, which is called like this in CMD:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\BoLPad\SyntaxCheck\\luac5.1.exe" C:\Users\Andi-PC\Desktop\test\syntax.lua
```

-> So i call the program and as parameter the file to be checked.
Now i'm trying to get the result of the check (so the output in CMD) to my C# Application.

I'm wondering if it's possible, i tried alot even using >command.txt to get the file out of the CMD, but there's nothing in it. So i either need a working output of the text out of CMD or get the CMD text... Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a process and redirecting the output stream like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\BoLPad\SyntaxCheck\luac5.1.exe", @"C:\Users\Andi-PC\Desktop\test\syntax.lua");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Gives me no output at all, had this problem before... In the CMD window it shows the text that i wanted to get.

Comment: @user3002079 Check the code again, I updated it to fix an error. If that still doesnt work try reading from the Error stream instead of the Output stream, I have seen some commandline apps do that for some reason.

Comment: WOW! Thanks, really! Redirecting ErrorOutput was the right thing to do here ;) I tried so much to get the text, still not getting it can be something different than usual output. Thanks !