# Run Exe from ActionResult

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, doc, libreoffice

I'm trying to convert a doc to html and this is the code I use. 
The problem is that I have no exception but I did not create the file. 
I've tried various alternatives but do not know how to proceed.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //check if file is ok
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"),
                                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = ("soffice.exe");
            psi.Arguments = string.Format("--headless --convert-to htm:HTML --outdir " + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/batch/") + " \"{0}\"", path);
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I've updated the code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //check if file is ok
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"),
                                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/LOP/App/libreoffice/program/"), "soffice.exe");
            psi.Arguments = string.Format("--headless --convert-to htm:HTML --outdir " + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/batch/") + " \"{0}\"", path);
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();
           string myString = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(myString);
            proc.WaitForExit();
            var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

But Exitcode still 0 and myString is empty :(

--SOLUTION-- 
All code are ok! a process of libroffice was left hanging in memory and then every other request appending without give a results, the strange thing is that libreoffice continues to give exitcode 0 to all process in memory

Comment: What is the return code of your process?  If its anything other than zero, you are getting an error.

Comment: How i can get the return code ?

Comment: `var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;`

Comment: well as i suspect it is zero :(

Comment: @MVCisMyBestFriend: In terms of return values that indicate if something went according to plan, `0` is usually indicative that it succeeded. Could be different for libre office, but I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You can either query the `ExitCode` property on your Process instance after the process exits to check if the process executed without errors or you can read what's happening in the console from the `StandardOutput` property (however make sure to set `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to true and `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to false as it is advised on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput).

Comment: I've set all but the return value is zero and into console nothing appears

Comment: Are you sure the arguments that you're providing to soffice.exe are valid? I'm not seeing all of these arguments as part of the tool's documentation. Check https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: Yes they are ok! i've saved a batch file with the same commands and if i launch is ok! I'm using libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to problem will be better understood by getting the output of your process.  On your "psi" variable, set "RedirectStandardOutput = true" before you call "proc.Start();" then to access the output, add a line like the one below and set a breakpoint on it (or the line after it).

```
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

For more info, check this existing post below, look at the accepted answer ;-)

[Capturing the console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)