# How do I embed a batch file in a vb program?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple VB program. I just want it to embed into it a running batch program. I'm asking if there is a way to do that.

So to break it down could i take a batch file and embed it into the program.
So it would kind of be like this except its not two windows: http://gyazo.com/72652af4dfc04cd379ee11ed0de165e2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1) It's probably silly to have a separate .bat file if you can do everything you want directly in the VB program.  Have you considered just incorporating the functionality directly in VB?

2) To run a separate .bat file from VB.Net, perhaps the easiest way is to use Process.start().

EXAMPLE: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\path\to\myfile.bat")`

3) Finally, you can always a) create a text file (with a .bat suffix and your .bat commands) on the fly, then call "Process.Start()" on your dynamically-created .bat file.

PS:

I assume by "VB" you probably mean "VB.Net".  If you mean "VB6", the API would be "Shell()".  For example: `Shell("c:\path\to\myfile.bat", vbHide)`.

Comment: Wait, But is there a way to embed the output in the program??

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean "embed the output in the program"?  Can you give an example?

Comment: PS: Strong suggestion - please re-word your post.  I think there's a valid question in there.  I'm disappointed in the anal retentive trolls who marked you down and closed it without asking you to elaborate.

Comment: Reworded, added detail

Comment: Sorry - I'm still not sure what you're asking for :(

Comment: Ok so you know like JFrame were you can embed webpages. I want to embed a batch file in a vb program. so instead of web pages, like batch files

Comment: You may start the batch file as a new process and then capture the output. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c