# How do i read the output from a batch file in a vb program

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

thanks in advance i just want to know if theres a way to read the output from a running batch file in a vb.net program. Thanks!

Comment: need more information

Comment: Batch file is actually ambiguous, but I think it's safe to assume you mean a batch file (.bat) for the command console/window (cmd.exe). and by output you mean.. printed to screen, right?..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I embed a batch file in a vb program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727564/how-do-i-embed-a-batch-file-in-a-vb-program)

Comment: doesn't seem like a duplicate of the question..

Comment: however, it is a duplicate of this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c

Comment: Is it already running separately? Is it launched from the .NET program?

Comment: It is running Separately

Comment: you can let the batch output to be in a txt file and then you can read the txt file that contains the output

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter above mentions, you can run the batch file in a shell within your VB.NET program and then read the directed output. I have done this exactly in previous project.

Here is a code snippet which shows how you can do it:

```
Dim outputFile As String = """" & Path.GetTempFileName & """"
Dim batchCommand As String = """C:\Path\To\MyFile.bat"">" & outputFile

Dim cmdProcess As New Process
With cmdProcess
    .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " & batchCommand)
    With .StartInfo
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With
    .Start()
    .WaitForExit()
End With

' This is the output from the batch file.
Dim batchOutput As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(outputFile)
```