# Redirect Console.WriteLine() output to string

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to take `Console.WriteLine()` output, and append to a string. I cannot change the Main method to simply append to a string instead of writing to console - I need a method to read all written lines from the console and append them to a string.

Currently, I have been using a `FileStream` and redirecting console output into a text file, and then reading from that.

```
var fs = new FileStream("dataOut.txt", FileMode.Create);
var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.SetError(sw);
```

And then `Console.WriteLine("whatever")` writes to the text file. However, I would like to do this without going back and forth from a text file.

Is something like this possible? I realize that the example below does not.

```
string outString = "";
Console.SetOut(outString);
Console.SetError(outString);
```

Comment: *"I cannot change the Main method to simply append to a string instead of writing to console"* Why not?

Comment: why don't you store the information in a `StringBuilder Object` then when you are done write the information to a text file that way

Comment: @EdPlunkett because I didn't write the code, and do not have the permission to modify it.

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c) might help

Comment: @Irey I hope you're taking a break from this nonsense now and then to look at job ads.

Comment: @15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153: you certainly never use Console.WriteLine() but have written your code in a way that Main() returns a StringBuffer instead ... ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [`StringWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.SetError(sw);
Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");
string result = sw.ToString();
```