# How can a CSharpScript process to capture the output generated by a vbscript or cs-script?

Tags: vbscript, cs-script

Is there a way for the hosting process to capture the output generated by a vbScript or cs-script when that script is run by CSharpScript(Rosslyn) ?

I am running a Rosslyn script in C#. I would like to log the Console or Trace output generated by the script. I expected something similar to OpenStandardOutput in System.Console, but am not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

When your CSharpScript is executed it is simply running as code within your calling process. If you want to capture its output you can use the technique of starting a new process to run the script and redirecting its output.

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers.