# Read output from another application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ipc, c#-2.0

I am not a developer but I have to create a small application. The scenario is 
we have an existing financial application. When the application completes calculation it will pass a few parameters. My C# application needs to read these parameters(financial application output parameters).If the primary application (financial application) doesn't pass the parameter then the C# application ask to input these parameters(input in textboxes). Can anyone help me on how I can read these parameters in my C# windows form application.

Comment: Is that primary (financial) application a console one which returns output data to standard output? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c if this is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

Comment: Why the tags "C#-4.0" and "C#-2.0"? Can you use those versions, but not "C#-3.0"? Seems weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your financial application writes the output to the command line, your C# application cannot pick up these results. The financial app needs to write out the results to a file in some format and your C# can in turn read this file and process them.

**UPDATE**

Look into calling an application from using Process(). Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output) how to run an application using Process() and getting it's output.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: thanks, yes financial application will output to command line. Any solution?

Comment: @Sinatr The user has mentioned he is not a developer. A little help no matter how strange the question wouldn't hurt anyone.