# How to get the text from a pop-up box generated from cmd?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, cmd

I'm trying to get the activation status of Windows. I've got this code:

```
 Process proc = new Process();


 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C slmgr /xpr";
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 proc.Start();

 string x = "";

 while (!proc.HasExited)
 {
     x += proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 }

 return x;
```

As some of you may know, the command "slmgr /xpr" will make a pop-up appear informing you of your Windows activation status.

Executing this code, I get the pop-up box (and "x" is empty).
What I want is to get the text that's in it (so it appears on a label in my form). I wonder if there's any way to extract just the text from inside the pop-up that appears, in this case it would be something like "the machine is permanently activated".

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slmgr` is actually a VBScript file not an executable, when you run it it will default to using the *WScript* runtime which is for windowed scripts and uses Message Boxes for default output. If you change to *CScript* you will get console output:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nologo \"" + Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "slmgr.vbs") + "\" /xpr";
```

You can then capture this: [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

You could also look inside the script file, see whats its doing & reimplement it in your code (ymmv).

Comment: That's really what I needed, thanks! However I'd really like to know, how can I look inside the script file? I'm kind of a beginner here, sorry

Comment: It's VBScript so its just a text file, open it in any text editor.

Comment: Thank you again :)