# ASP.net nesting routes with Route tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm brand new to C# and ASP.Net

I am trying to model some endpoints:

```
/api/sites/
/api/sites/{id}/
/api/sites/{id}/readers/
/api/sites/{id}/readers/{id}/
```

I already have a `SitesController`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SitesController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
    public ActionResult<Site> Get(string id) {}



}
```

I've tried adding a `ReadersController` inside the `SitesController` class

```
[Route("{id:length(24)}/[controller]}")]
[ApiController]
public class ReadersController {
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "test";
}
```

I can't hit the endpoint `/api/sites/{id}/readers/` though so I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Is there some way I can do this while still using the `[Route]` tags?

Comment: You can not and do not need to create nested controller classes. You need to create `ReadersController` class same as `SitesController` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be nesting controller classes. Make a new class for `ReadersController` then setup the routes like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SitesController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet("{siteId:length(24)}")]
    public ActionResult<Site> Get(string siteId) {}
}

[Route("api/sites/{siteId:length(24)}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReadersController {
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "test";

    [HttpGet("{readerId:length(24)}")]
    public ActionResult<Site> Get(string siteId, string readerId) {}
}
```

You can use `routes.MapRoute` to create more complex rules however if you want to keep it easy and specify routes for each individual endpoint then you can carry on using `HttpGet` or `Route` attributes. Or if you want to make it explicit you can write out the whole route in each `HttpGet` and ignore the `Route` attribute on the controller.

Comment: can i access `siteId` inside of `ReadersController`?

Comment: @Smarticles101 yes, you have to put it as a parameter though. I have just updated my answer as I missed that.

Comment: sweet, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are building apis with asp.net core, please check this.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

You can use `routes.MapRoute` functions as many as you can.
Like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default_route",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default_route",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/readers/{id?}");
```