# How to start a subprocess in c#

Tags: c#, process, console

So i am trying to start a process in C# but most of the other stackoverflow anwsers show how to start a process either in a completely new window or print the output one it is finished which is not what i want. I want the process to start in the current console window and be able to write lines and read them. So practically a process in a process. Is there any way to do that in C#?

Comment: Like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=net-5.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)