# Unable to retain shell input prefix when starting powershell process from C# and capturing its output, while allowing input writing to it manually

Tags: c#, terminal

I am trying to preserve the input line at the bottom of powershell, but do not know how.

This is what I am doing. It builds on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c).

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class ConsoleApplication
{
    static void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("process exited with code {0}\n", /*process.ExitCode.ToString()*/));
        Console.WriteLine("Exited");
    }

    static void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
        process.Exited += new System.EventHandler(process_Exited);

        //process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        //process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ver";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

I expect the following when I type `hello`

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.
>
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
>
> PS C:\Users\MyUser>hello

Instead I get

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.
>
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
>
> hello

Can I preserve the bottom input prefix?

I eventually want to use this over ssh and would like to maintain the directory path prefix.